# how can I optimise below mysql query (I am new to optimisation)

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

How can I optimize this MySQL query?

Execution plan is also mentioned below.

```
Select 
    tlk.id, um.store_users_id 
from 
    user_modules um 
inner join 
    module_chapters mc on um.modules_id =  mc.modules_id 
                       and mc.comment_status = 1 
                       and um.modules_id = 3697 
                       and mc.chapters_id = 4083 
inner join 
    context con on con.module_id = mc.modules_id 
                and con.chapter_id = mc.chapters_id 
inner join  
    user_talks tlk on tlk.contextId = con.id 
                   and tlk.context_scope = 1 
left join 
    talk_associated_users tau on tau.talk_id = tlk.id 
                              and tau.target_store_user_id = um.store_users_id 
where 
    tau.target_store_user_id is null
```

[![plan of the above query][1]][1]

Comment: please format properly

Comment: Mention what you've tried. This has the look of a homework problem.

Comment: I just tried with "explain" to see the execution plan..What actually is explain doing? I mean how can i understand the order in which query is executed from explain ?

Comment: Simplle matter of reading the documentation for explain

Comment: Can u tell me what is mean by execution plan?? Does that mean order of exection of a mysql query?

Answer (score 0):

Run `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` and provide the results.

```
                   and mc.comment_status = 1 
                   and um.modules_id = 3697 
                   and mc.chapters_id = 4083
```

These smell like things that belong in the `WHERE` clause, not in `JOIN...ON`.

On `mc`, this may be optimal:

```
INDEX(chapters_id, comment_status)
```

On `um`, this may be optimal:

```
INDEX(modules_id)
```

The `EXPLAIN`, especially after adding those indexes, may lead to even better indexes.